# Phonegap and Nova Data Framework -

Tags: iphone, sqlite, cordova

I am learning PhoneGap for an app project and need to use the database for certain aspects, I am trying out the Nova Data framework,

https://cordova.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20use%20nova.data

I am trying to use my code to put together a test entity, but I am getting a db error telling me there is a missing table.  The documentation does not specify that the database should be created beforehand, but I am starting to think that may be the case.  Has anyone out there used the Nova framework in a project?  I just need a little guidance.

Here is my code I am using to kick off the DB Context:

```
var DataContext = function () {
    nova.data.DbContext.call(this, "HealthDb", "1.0", "Health DB", 1000000);
    this.Temperatures = new nova.data.Repository(this, Temperature, "Temperatures");
};
DataContext.prototype = new nova.data.DbContext();
DataContext.constructor = DataContext;
```

And my entity (Temperature) :

```
var Temperature = function () {
    nova.data.Entity.call(this);
    this.Value = 101;
};
Temperature.prototype = new nova.data.Entity();
Temperature.constructor = Temperature;
```

It is creating an empty database with the proper name, just no tables!  I am grateful for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was trying to start up the dbcontext before I defined my entity classes....

Changed the order of my js files and it works.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for using our library. I have made the html5 sqlite as a standalone library. Please get it from [github](https://github.com/leotsai/html5sqlite).

A live demo link is also available there. And the documentation is more complete. The lib itself has also been updated and a few bugs fixed.

Thanks,

Leo

Comment: is there any complete documentation available for nova framework. I checked on site but it is not available. i suppose you are not available on twitter as well.